# charset="utf-8" not displaying special characters

Tags: php, html, encoding, utf-8

I'm using PHP to display people's information from a text file in an HTML table. Some of the text contains special characters (Köhler, François, František) and those characters are displayed as "�". I know this is because the encoding isn't set to `charset="UTF-8"`, but I've set it using PHP's `header()` function as well as in the meta data in the `<head>`. In addition, I used Notepad to specifically save the file encoding as UTF-8.

When I inspect the page with
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> **> Network > Headers**
it includes "Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8" under "Response Headers", so I think the browser should be getting the idea that the encoding is UTF-8.

What am I missing here?

Here's the code where I declare the charset in the PHP file

```
<?php
   header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');
   $ary_of_lines = file("customers.txt");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta name="description" content="">
   <meta name="author" content="">
   ....... more stuff .......
```

Comment: and what encoding has `"customers.txt"`, try `utf8_encode();` on the lines

Comment: Try this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp

Comment: @JOUM got it, changed "customers.txt" encoding to UTF-8. Thanks!